# Jdbc Connection Refrences set to null

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working on some old code and i found that the jdbc connection is being passed on as parameter of a method from one class to another.
When the application is run, jdbc connection leaks are observed. The connection is being closed in the same function from where it is being passed.
Should the connection be closed in every method in which it is being passed as a parameter ?
If it is not required, then can i set the connection to null in every method ? Or please suggest if there is any other way to clear connection leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure the connection is closed in the same method that opens it. Nothing else will work. The connection should be closed in a `finally` block to ensure it happens.

> Can I set the connection to null in every method?

Only if you like writing pointless code. Setting things to null doesn't close anything, or cure connection leaks, or indeed accomplish anything at all in the case of parameters to a method which is about to exit.

Comment: The connection is closed in same method in finally block but still causes connection leaks. i am doubting that due to the connection being passed in other methods and being used there also, it is somehow causing connection leaks.

Answer (score -1):

yes definitely you have to close the connection in each method. if your project architecture is mvc. you have some DAO classes in the classes you have the persistence logic. so before closing the connection make sure that the connection is alive or not, make a condition like.

```
if(connection!=null) {
connection.close();
}
```

Comment: If you close the connection in each method, the calling method won't be able to continue using it. The suggestion doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry i mean it each dao class  i am really sorry that instead of writing  each class i written in each method.